# How to format Oracle APEX region items with CSS?

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a region item (select list) that I want to move all the way to the right. Is there way to use CSS to float the entire select list to the right. I have tried many different ways and still unsuccessful. I am running Oracle Application Express 4.2. Any help would be appreciated.

For example I currently have this below:

```
Select List1  Select List2
```

I want this result below:

```
Select List1                                                   Select List 2
```

Here is a screenshot of what I have below. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh, Apex 4.2 ... I can't remember exactly any more, but - is there any option (for the Select List item) that lets you choose which column will that item be in? If it is set to "Automatic", change it to a higher number (for example, 8). It might be easier if you can switch the "view grid" on so that you would actually see which column contains what.

Yes, I know - setting it to a fixed column won't make it *dynamic*, but might mimic what you're after.

Another option might be to split items into 2 or 3 subregions placed in parallel. The first one would contain Select List 1, the second one would be fixed in size (so that it would occupy the middle portion of the page, while the third one would contain Select List 2.

Workarounds, workarounds ... Sorry for not being able to help you any better & smarter.

Comment: It still depends on the theme used, but it sure looks like that one can use the grid layout